# Get path of file with double backslash

Tags: java

I am doing this:

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/logo.png")));
```

in order to have the entire path file name.
But this instruction below fails:

```
byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'file:\C:\Users\thomas\dev\workspace\myapp\target\classes\images\logo.png' does not exist
```

It's because it needs to have double backslash instead of single backslash (OS: Windows). Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: "It's because it needs to have double backslash instead of single backslash" — No, it has nothing to do with that. You misunderstand the purpose of escape sequences. The real reason is that the path does not exist, just as the error message says.

Comment: the file does exist. I have tried with C:\\Users\\thomas\\dev\\workspace\\myapp\\target\\classes\\images\\logo.png and it works.

Comment: Remove the `file:\ ` in front of the `file` string. But this code won't work once you bundle your code into a JAR file. You cannot treat resources as files (because they generally aren't!). You need to read it as a resource stream! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/1968

Comment: Are you aware that a string **literal** `"C:\\Users\\thomas"` represents the actual String **value** `C:\Users\Thomas`? In other words, your idea that you need double backslashes is a red herring. The problem is the presence of `file:\C:\...`, which should be just `C:\...`. And that is because resources are not (necessarily) files! If you want to get data from a resource, use `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. File `logo.png` obviously contains an [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html). You apparently want to create an actual `Image` from that file and do something with the created `Image` - maybe use it as an [Icon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) in a _Swing_ application. There are other ways to create an `Image` besides converting the file to a `byte` array. I believe that you really want to know how to convert your "resource" to an `Image`.

Comment: yes , I want to insert the image in a thymeleaf email template. I couldnt figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You probably want the `getResourceAsStream` function. As noted in the comments, you do **NOT** want to use `File` for this, as it will reference things on the file system (things that will not be there once you build & deploy your app).

A simple demo of reading a Java resource is below:

```java
    public void readResourceBytes()
    {
        final String resourceName = "images/logo.png";
        final ByteArrayOutputStream mem = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (final InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName))
        {
            copy(is, mem);
        }

        byte[] fileContent = mem.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(mem.toByteArray());

        // Or, maybe you just want the ASCII text
        // String fileContent = mem.toString();
        // System.out.println(mem.toString());
    }

    // OK for binary files, not OK for text, should use Reader/Writer instead
    public static void copy(final InputStream from, final OutputStream to) throws IOException
    {
        final int bufferSize = 4096;

        final byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len;
        while (0 < (len = from.read(buf)))
        {
            to.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        to.flush();
    }
```